# How to read a PHP variable as a numeric variable to make some calculation?

Tags: php, int

I am having problems with a variable which reads 17,50 for calculation. The variable is part of an array and i am just getting the value 17.00

```
$product_price_tmp = intval(str_replace(",",".",$custom_values['product_price'][0]));
```

and i tried the following

```
$product_sub_total = sprintf("%.2f",$product_price_tmp);//reads 17.00
$product_sub_total = $product_price_tmp;//reads 17
```

I didn't notice the problem as all my test price values were rounded numbers.

Any tips?

Comment: why are you using intval() if you want a float?

Comment: Have you tried without `intval()`?

Comment: Use `floatval()` instead of `intval()`

Comment: Arrrgggh, totally overlooked intval vs floatval, thanks guys (girls)

Answer (score 2):

Replace this

```
$product_price_tmp = intval(str_replace(",",".",$custom_values['product_price'][0]));
```

with this

```
$product_price_tmp = floatval(str_replace(",",".",$custom_values['product_price'][0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `intval` since it is not `int` you intend to get. It is enough to cast float type here:

```
$product_price_tmp = (float) str_replace(",",".",$custom_values['product_price'][0]);
var_dump($product_price_tmp);

//float 17.5
```